# Is there a lamb dish that is as easy to prepare as steak?

Tags: lamb

I need to cook a romantic dinner and my wife wants lamb, which I've never cooked before.
Usually I make us steaks in a cast iron - it's easy, tasty and quick.
Can I do something similar with lamb? What is the name of the cut I need to buy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the ones that look like little tiny T-bone steaks.  Typically they are called Lamb Chops, but look first as there are different cuts under that name.   You might also consider doing a rack, which is the equivalent to a Rib Roast, but obviously much smaller.  For the rack, I'd sear it in a pan, and then broil it until done. (15-25 minutes, 140-160 degrees).

Comment: That's what I got and cooked - t-bone ones. Turned out great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the UK I'd use a cut called lamb leg steak, as you can prepare it in a similar way to beef steak. Personally I prefer to griddle on one side, flip over and finish in a hot oven. Make sure you rest it!

I know recipe requests are a bit *ugh* here, but I'd recommend making the lamb steaks a little bit spiced (rub with cumin, chilli & coriander) and serve with a smooth, creamy cauliflower puree - it's a great combination.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Creamy cauliflower puree - should I chill it before serving?

Comment: +1 for the spicing.  Also could use a mild curry powder.

Comment: @z-boss - no, don't chill it. Also serve some greens, say wilted buttery spinach, and perhaps a red wine reduction sweetened with redcurrant jelly. If you don't want to use spices, try taking half a lamb stock cube (the paste kind), schmush it with a little olive oil, then rub that onto the lamb steaks as seasoning.

Comment: I'd simmer cauliflower in some veg stock, then when very tender reserve the liquid and pop the cauli in a blender. Add a few tablespoons of the liquid and whizz until fine. Add some cream, then keep adding more liquid until you like the texture, and season to taste. Reheat in a saucepan when needed. And yes, serve with some lovely fresh greens too as per @ElendilTheTail.

Answer (score 4):

I love lamb burgers. You grind lamb, then mix it with onions and various spices. You then put them on a spit and either broil them in the oven or cook them on a grill. You serve inside grilled pita them with tzatziki (a yogurt and cucumber sauce) and taboulleh (a bulghur salad). The latter is optional, it's just a nice side dish.

Answer (score 3):

Roast Lamb Loin is very easy. 30mins per 500g on 180 degrees. Seasoned with salt is the minimum; however it's easy to add Rosemary or Mint. It works very well with a large range of sides including salads, purees, or roast vegetables. A good wine match is a full bodied red such as Sharaz or Syrah.

Answer (score 2):

You can't go past Lamb Backstrap . It does everything a steak does in regards to cooking, remains very juicy and tender. 
You can wrap in prosciutto , serve with soft polenta. Basically whatever your imagination can come up with it will suit this cut.Only down side is the price to purchase, but well worth it for a romantic dinner.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that cut.  It's probably a regional term.  Can you add a picture?